# gtkmm linker error

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, g++, gtkmm

**Hello stackoverflow:), 
I am compiling a basic gui program that takes sums of 2 doubles and prints them out. My code is actually pretty simple, I will first post the 3 files that I compile by commandline**

```
"g++ main.cc examplewindow.cc -o main `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`"
```

**The error on the commandline is:**

```
/tmp/ccSeXudb.o: In function `ExampleWindow::on_button_clicked_calculate()': examplewindow.cc:(.text+0x1e70): undefined reference to `ExampleWindow::double_to_ustring(double)'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**These are the 3 files:**

```
                                    examplewindow.h

#ifndef GTKMM_EXAMPLEWINDOW_H
#define GTKMM_EXAMPLEWINDOW_H

#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

class ExampleWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
  ExampleWindow();
  virtual ~ExampleWindow();

protected:
  //Signal handlers:
  void on_checkbox_editable_toggled();
  void on_checkbox_visibility_toggled();
  Glib::ustring get_entry1();
  Glib::ustring get_entry2();
  std::string double_to_ustring(double a);
  void on_button_clicked_calculate();
  void on_button_close();

  //Child widgets:
  //Gtk::Box m_HBox;
  Gtk::Box m_VBox;
  Gtk::Box m_ZBox;
  Gtk::Entry m_Entry, m_Entry2, m_Entry3; 
  Gtk::Button m_Button_Close, m_Button_Calculate;
  //Gtk::CheckButton m_CheckButton_Editable, m_CheckButton_Visible;
  Gtk::Label m_Label_Sum, m_Label_Equals;
};

#endif //GTKMM_EXAMPLEWINDOW_H





                                     main.cc

#include "examplewindow.h"
#include <gtkmm/application.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv,     "org.gtkmm.example");

  ExampleWindow window;

  //Shows the window and returns when it is closed.
  return app->run(window);
}




                                  examplewindow.cc

#include "examplewindow.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>


ExampleWindow::ExampleWindow()
: m_VBox(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL),
  m_ZBox(Gtk::ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL),
  m_Button_Calculate("Calculate"),
  m_Button_Close("Close")
{
  set_size_request(200, 100);
  set_title("Trial Version:P");

  add(m_VBox);


  m_VBox.add(m_ZBox);

  m_Entry.set_max_length(50);
  m_Entry.set_text("First");
  m_Entry.set_text(m_Entry.get_text() + " value");
  m_Entry.select_region(0, m_Entry.get_text_length());
  m_ZBox.pack_start(m_Entry);

  m_Label_Sum.set_text("+");
  m_ZBox.pack_start(m_Label_Sum); 

  m_Entry2.set_max_length(50);
  m_Entry2.set_text("Second");
  m_Entry2.set_text(m_Entry2.get_text() + " value");
  m_Entry2.select_region(0, m_Entry2.get_text_length());
  m_ZBox.pack_start(m_Entry2);

  m_Label_Equals.set_text("=");
  m_ZBox.pack_start(m_Label_Equals);

  m_Entry3.set_max_length(50);
  m_Entry3.set_text("The");
  m_Entry3.set_text(m_Entry3.get_text() + " result"); 
  m_Entry3.set_editable(0); 
  m_Entry3.select_region(0, m_Entry3.get_text_length());
  m_ZBox.pack_start(m_Entry3);


  m_Button_Calculate.signal_clicked().connect( sigc::mem_fun(*this,     &ExampleWindow::on_button_clicked_calculate) );
  m_VBox.pack_start(m_Button_Calculate);
  m_Button_Calculate.set_can_default();
  m_Button_Calculate.grab_default();
  m_Button_Close.signal_clicked().connect( sigc::mem_fun(*this,
              &ExampleWindow::on_button_close) );
  m_VBox.pack_start(m_Button_Close);
  m_Button_Close.set_can_default();
  m_Button_Close.grab_default();

  show_all_children();
}

ExampleWindow::~ExampleWindow()
{
}

Glib::ustring ExampleWindow::get_entry1()
{
  return m_Entry.get_text();
}

Glib::ustring ExampleWindow::get_entry2()
{
  return m_Entry2.get_text();
}
std::string double_to_ustring(double a)
{
  std::string str = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(a);
  return str; 
}

void ExampleWindow::on_button_clicked_calculate()
{ 
  Glib::ustring a = get_entry1();
  Glib::ustring b = get_entry2();
  double m = std::atof( a.c_str() ) + std::atof( b.c_str() );
  Glib::ustring z = double_to_ustring(m);
  m_Entry3.set_text(z);
}

void ExampleWindow::on_button_close()
{
  hide();

}
```

I have made a c++ only version of it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string double_to_string(double a)
{
  string str = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(a);
  return str; 
}

int main()
{
  string a="3", b="5";
  double m = atof( a.c_str() ) + atof( b.c_str() );
  string z = double_to_string(m);
  cout << z << endl;
}
```

c++ version works, so I need help. How do I get the linker working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your examplewindow.cc file you are defining `std::string double_to_ustring(double a)` out of the ExampleWindow class. You need to qualify it like every other member method of the class: `std::string ExampleWindow::double_to_ustring(double a)`